# Error inserting valid 4-byte UTF-8 sequence into MySQL

Tags: mysql, go, unicode, utf-8

I have the following UTF-8 byte string I'm trying to store in a MySQL table (utf8mb4) but getting a failure from the mysql server.

```
...
db.Exec("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'; SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;")

var badBytes = []byte{
    34, 48, 34, 32, 47, 62, 66, 117, 121, 32, 105, 116, 32, 110, 111, 119, 32,
    240, 159, 147, 149, 32, 60, 97, 32, 104, 114, 101, 102, 61, 34, 104, 116,
}

fmt.Println("UTF8 Valid", utf8.Valid(badBytes))
fmt.Println()
fmt.Println(string(badBytes))
fmt.Println()

res, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO demo (body) VALUES (?)", string(badBytes))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

id, err := res.LastInsertId()
fmt.Println(id, err)
```

The output is below

```
UTF8 Valid true

="1" border="0" />Buy it now  <a href="ht_tl

Error 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x93\x95 <...' for column 'body' at row 1
```

The MySQL table and connections are all `utf8mb4`:

```
CREATE TABLE `demo` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `body` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Did you try what says in charset here: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql ?

Comment: Does your API allow multiple statements??  Check for errors after every `db.exec()`.

Answer (score 0):

[Like @Rico said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288165/error-inserting-valid-utf8-byte-sequence-into-mysql#comment69780515_41288165) I needed to specify the collation (utf8mb4_unicode_ci) so the go-mysql lib didn't default to `utf8` and cause problems with my 4byte unicode runes (mysql's utf8 only supports up to 3byte unicode).

```
[username[:password]@][protocol[(address)]]/dbname?collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

See the [go-sql-driver readme](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#charset) for more information.

Comment: The `SET NAMES utf8mb4` _should_ have compensated for the lack of specification to the driver.